# what meaning do you derive from the phrase 'innocently obnoxious'?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

I would like to know if my phrase "innocently obnoxious" infers what I really want it to.
From the following sentence what meaning do you derive from 'innocently obnoxious'?

***James was in the front seat, Kyle in the back, asking the innocently obnoxious questions only kids can get away with.***

Comment: How should we know whether it infers what you want it to. You don't tell us what you want it to infer! Unclear question.

Comment: I wanted to know what a reader would take from it, without my direct influence. me telling you would defeat the purpose.

Comment: We are not here to read and interpret sentences for you, sorry. These kinda of questions only benefit the OP and not the community/site.

Answer (score 1):

I perceive that "Kyle" is asking irritating questions without realizing. However, *obnoxious* tends to have the connotation of being deliberate, so the sentence could be interpreted as a bit of an oxymoron.

Comment: Agreed. "Kyle was asking obnoxious questions with child-like naïvety". The questions are obnoxious but the person asking the questions is not aware of their obnoxious nature, innocently obnoxious doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Note that your phrase might *imply* something, not *infer* it. Somebody reading or hearing it might *infer* (i.e. conclude or deduce) what was implied.

Comment: "*I perceive*" and "*could be interpreted*" tell us nothing about whether the sentence means what the OP intends. That intention is not even stated!